# Which are the countries where vegan diet is more popular?

Tags: veganism, statistics

Are there any statistics measuring what percentage of the population of some countries are following a vegan diet?

Comment: Veganism has become popular around decade. Hence there would be very less percentage of populations. If you ask for vegetarians, then there would be some stats.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is **currently no reliable dataset that would include the kind of information you are asking about**. Although for vegetarianism (with veganism included) there is some data, for veganism it is only for a couple of countries and even for these, the sources are somewhat dubious (like for Israel, where these are estimated by a television poll).

Speaking of **Israel** though, if the data from the poll can be taken at face value, it is **the country with biggest percentage of population that is vegan - 5%**. As a piece of interesting trivia, the Israeli army provides [vegan meals](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2015/12/big-in-israel-vegan-warriors/413149/) to their soldiers as well as [leather-free boots and wool-free berets](http://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2015/12/10/459212839/why-so-many-israeli-soldiers-are-going-vegan).

The other (known) [countries with rather big percentage of vegans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarianism_by_country) are for example **Sweden** (approximately 4% of the population), **Japan** (2.7% - you have to believe Wikipedia or read Japanese on [this one](http://www.arcj.org/information/00/id=560)) and **possibly Italy** (for which the number is estimated between 0.6% to 2.8%). Other countries with more than 1% of population being vegan are - **United Kingdom, United States, Germany** and **Poland**.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of top 10 countries which has the maximum vegetarian percentage in the world.

India's vegetarians make up around a third of India's population, and two-thirds
 of the world's vegetarian population.

> 1. India -- 29% - 40%
> 2. Italy -- 7.1% - 10%
> 3. Ethiopia
> 4. Lebanon
> 5. Turkey
> 6. United Kingdom -- 2% - 12%
> 7. USA -- 3.3%
> 8. Singapore
> 9. Jamaica
> 10. Israel -- 2.6% - 13%

**NOTE**

The list is according to https://collectively.org/article/the-10-most-vegetarian-countries-in-the-world-in-order-of-meatlessness/

The percentages are according to `wikipedia`. But the percentages are based on different years.

Comment: The question asks about **vegans** not **vegetarians**.

Comment: @neophyte Thanks  for the answer; I was asking for vegans. However knowing about vegetarians is interesting too..

Comment: Apologies I misread the question. I would edit my answer.