# Which countries have the highest number of vegans?

Tags: veganism, statistics

Which countries have the highest number of vegans? And which has the highest percentage of vegans?

Comment: see also https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1957/which-country-has-the-highest-number-of-vegetarians

Comment: @jsotola You could use Wikipedia as the basis for an answer :)

Comment: @jsotola that's now how SE works. We're trying to map & index all questions about vegetarianism & veganism here. I created this question to aid in that effort. Yes, it's an easy one to answer with well-sourced materials listed in the references section on wikipedia. Feel free to draft an answer for this question citing those sources :)

Comment: @jsotola to add to Michael's points, a good SE answer often provides some context and explanation rather than just a simple "this country" response. Please note that you don't have to participate in questions you aren't interested in, and you are always welcome to bring concerns to [meta] for a more extended discussion of whether any given question is a good fit for the site. I appreciate differing perspectives on this, as long as we're all working within the Code of Conduct and other guidelines!

Comment: see also https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/518/which-are-the-countries-where-vegan-diet-is-more-popular/523#523

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to HappyCow article Israel has the highest percentage of vegans globally summing between 5-8% of its whole population.

[Link 1](https://www.happycow.net/vegtopics/travel/top-vegan-friendly-cities#:%7E:text=Israel%20has%20the%20highest%20percentage,these%20vegans%20inhabit%20Tel%20Aviv.)

That is if we consider vegan a 365days choice. If we speak just about avoiding eating animal products for a certain number of days, Greece seems to be the most vegan country in the world due to its religion that includes 180days of fasting(avoiding animal products) per year.

[Link 2](https://sosfreevegans.com/which-country-has-the-most-vegans-what-about-vegetarians/)

Answer (score 2):

### Vegan in Sri Lanka

Of the countries I have visited Sri Lanka is the easiest to be vegan in, Pakistan the most difficult.

We have been visiting Sri Lanka since our honeymoon almost 40 years ago. first a month at a time, then three months, we built our dream home here in 2005 then started spending six months a year. Our daughter first came when she was two, our son was a baby his first visit. This time we have been here since Covid started going on two years now.

Sri Lanka is a Buddhist country, there have been various laws that prohibit the murder of cattle. Halal, (torturing ones dinner to death), is strictly forbidden. The Animal Act of Sri Lanka, (1958), prohibits the slaughter of cattle, cows and calves below the age of 12. The act made it economically unfeasible to raise cattle for 12 years before slaughter. On 29 September 2020, the cabinet approved the proposal on banning cattle slaughter permanently from the country.

The Animal Act also made it difficult to provide dairy. For every dairy cow born, there was likely a male that had to be supported for 12 years before it could offer it's flesh for consumption. Milk Powder is imported from New Zealand. Water Buffalo Curd, (~Yogurt), is available fresh.

Many Buddhist monks are vegan and provide a good example to the laypersons. In 2013 a Buddhist monk set himself on fire to protest Muslims eating beef.

The national meal in Sri Lanka is Rice and Curry. The curries are almost all vegan. Dahl, Potato, Bread Fruit, Jack Fruit, Banana Flower, Maniok, Various greens, Green Beans, Mushroom, TVP, Bean, Mixed Vegetable, Various Sambal,,, (now I'm making myself hungry). Coconut Milk is used in the cooking.

Egg Curry, an Omelet or Fish or Chicken may also be requested.

When dinning out there are many options, Rotis, (a meal wrapped in dough and grilled), Pizza, Indian, Chinese, Italian, Mexican, etc, all offering vegan dishes.
We have never entered a Sri Lankan restaurant where vegan food may not be ordered. The cooks know how to tone down the spices when asked. Many restaurants proudly advertise "No Pork on Premises".

I have not seen Honey here but Palm Treacle makes a great substitute.

Another plus is that we do not have a problem drinking the tap water or well water.

Comment: "laws that prohibit the murder of cattle" and "prohibits the slaughter of cattle...below the age of 12" I think you made a mistake here, because these statements are contradictory...

Comment: Michael Altfield: I do not understand the contradiction, please explain, **Webster : Murder : to slaughter wantonly : slay** https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/murder. For more Sri Lankan anti beef laws see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle_slaughter_in_Sri_Lanka

Answer (score 0):

The most friendly vegan country is Asia.
These countries are most popular among vegan citizens...
***India,
Bali,
Thailand,
Sri Lanka,
Taiwan,
Nepal.***
India has the highest percentage of vegans...

Comment: Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks!  But are those figures for vegetarians or for vegans?  It's not the same thing.

Comment: The question was strictly about vegans. Indians are mostly vegetarians.

Comment: I used to live in Thailand.  Being even vegetarian was a challenge.  It is being vegan here in the UK than Thailand.

Comment: I also used to live in Sri Lanka and the same applied.  I have not lived in India but I visited many times.  Being vegetarian is easy but vegan is more of a challenge.

Comment: Just also pointing out "Asia" is not a country

Comment: I am living in Sri Lanka. It is very easy being vegan here, (I am lacto ovo myself). Many monks are vegan and you seldom see an egg dish in rice and curry, the national meal. Milk products are hard to get although buffalo curd can be found.